# How to add custom action to the 'close' event after successful installation

Tags: wix, wix3.7

I have two msis and packed them into a bootstrapper EXE installer. But I want to have the ability to launch the application after installation. I know there's a way to achieve this by adding a 'launch' button. Then there will be two buttons when the installation succeeded. But is there a way to add a custom action to the 'close' button or remove the 'close' button?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Wix Burn UI is not a powerful for now, as far I know, however you can do anything you want, it's just matter of time you're willing to put in. Burn UI does not play well with properties for now, you can't even create custom TextBox to fill up a property, but if time is not a problem:

1) You can download Wix source, and modify everything the way you want it to be, making it reusable.

2) You can create custom WiX Burn UI(I like WPF+MVVM), which shouldn't take too much time, and should be very interesting. There you can include anything your soul wants.

3) You can disable WIx BURN UI and use MSI internalUI,
this is good example; http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/ui_and_localization/run_program_after_install.html

That will allow you to configfure everything, such as "Close" button having a custom action. + removing Close button by overriding custom dialogs(you can download them from wix, *.THM files)

Answer (score 1):

No, neither of those is possible.